# IP-Route multiple IPs from one NIC to Hyper-V instances

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012, ip-routing, rip

I have one root server @ server4you, unfortunately, S4U doesn't allow Bridging, so I am stuck with a problem!

I have 4 IPs mapped on one NIC and need to realise following configuration:

- XX.XX.XX.1 => localhost (the VM Host)
- xx.xx.xx.2 => exchange server
- xx.xx.xx.3 => sharepoint server
- xx.xx.xx.4 => office web apps server

How should I do it? I already stumbled over the keywords RIP and IP Routing.

Please help;)

Comment: do they have multiple vlans trunked on the single nic?

Comment: We are at the very beginning of the set up, so if it helps, we can do that!

Comment: Fabian784, did my answer suffice or is there anything else you need? If it did, kindly mark my answer appropriately or let me know if there's anything else you need! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just to set those IPs on the VMs in their respective network configurations, and *not* to set those IPs in the network configuration on the host.

So the host under its LAN configuration would have a single IP: XX.XX.XX.1

And the Exchange Server VM would have a single IP: XX.XX.XX.2

And so on, and so forth: the Hyper-V virtual switch will receive requests for XX.XX.XX.2 through .4 and route them to the respective virtual machines.

You may need to set up a virtual switch under Hyper-V Manager, and ensure that the external network is set to the single NIC, and check the box "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter":

[image: Virtual Switch Manager showing a LAN virtual switch set to share a NIC with VMs and the host operating system]

That virtual switch is then shared between the host and all VM guests, and so the VM guests can set their IP addresses and it will be as though you had all 4 operating systems behind a single switch.